# Persistent accessibility to a local network shared folder on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, startup, automount, shared-folders, 23.04

How can I ensure persistent accessibility to a local network shared folder located at /run/user/1001/gvfs/afp-volume:host=test.local,user=anonymous,volume=Public/Shared/Test on my Ubuntu 23.04 machine?

I'd like to avoid manually login to the system and connecting to the shared folder each time I restart the system.

Comment: How is the directory shared/accessible? `samba`, `ssh`, `ftp`? It looks like `samba`, but please verify. Do you need a password?

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu and the folder already exists. Can you please tell me how can I know How is the directory shared/accessible? 
Note: I don't need a password to access the folder @FelixJN

Comment: You should mount it somewhere else. The `/run/user/1001/` directory tree is deleted when you logout. Read `man fstab mount`.